# NodeJS express SOAP

Tags: node.js, express

I'm consuming a soap request with express and bodyparser, however the request is not properly formatted on consumption i.e the first equals (=) sign is converted to colon (:) i.e

Below is my code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
require('body-parser-xml')(bodyParser);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.xml());

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.send("hello");
});

app.post('/soap',function(req,res){
  req.setEncoding('utf8');
  var request = req.body;
  console.log(request);

  res.end("yes");
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port
  console.log("App listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Comment: The xml request looks as follows: <?xml version': '"1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: You should read [ask].

Comment: The client mostly likely isn't using the correct content type to upload the XML data, so Express thinks it's url-encoded data instead. See [the fine manual](https://github.com/fiznool/body-parser-xml#usage).

Comment: I'm using curl: curl -d @soap.xml "http://localhost:3000/url"

Comment: Also when I use postman,raw,it produces similar results

Comment: thanks @robertklep :)

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, the client was sending the data using incorrect (text) content type. With postman, ensure you set content type to text/xml or application/xml.